# sed won't match next line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have the following file called VERSIONSFILE:

```
[GUI]
Version="3.02.104"

[NOTGUI]
Version="1.05.24"

[ALSONOTGUI]
Version="3.01.230"
```

I am looking to replace the version number through a windows .bat file. Currently, I am using GNU sed to replace the file. The sed command I'm running is as follow:

> sed -r -i.bak -e "s/[GUI][\r\n]Version.*$/[GUI]\nVersion=\"3.02.108\"/gm" "VERSIONSFILE" "VERSIONSFILE"

From what I can tell, it should be matching and outputting the new version number as 3.02.108 instead. I checked my regular expression below and it is also correctly outputting my expected result.

https://regex101.com/r/GaSxKY/6

[GUI] first piece finds the [GUI] string.

[\r\n] matches any line feed, in this case I'm expecting \n, but figured adding both couldn't hurt.

Version.*$ matches on the whole version line to make sure it select everything and nothing more.

I have also tried using powershell replace, and am having the exact same issue, where it can't seem to pick up on the next line. Both methods I am able to replace 1 line, but not 2 at a time.

Comment: `sed` works on a per line basis. Use something like `sed -r -i.bak '/^\[GUI]$/{N;s/\nVersion.*/\nVersion="3.02.108"/}' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sed` works on a per line basis. There is [a special construct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235016/279389) that allows "slurping" the whole file into a single string, similar to `Get-Content -Raw` in powershell, but it makes sense to use `sed` special language here.

Use

```
sed -r -i.bak '/^\[GUI]$/{N;s/\nVersion.*/\nVersion="3.02.108"/}' file
# Or
sed -r -i.bak '/^\[GUI]$/{n;s/Version.*/Version="3.02.108"/}' file
```

Here,

- `/^\[GUI]$/` - finds a line that is equal to `[GUI]`

and then

- `N;` - reads the next line, appends `\n` and the line to the pattern space
- `s/\nVersion.*/\nVersion="3.02.108"/`  - replaces the newline (that is added by the `N` command) and the following line starting with `Version` with a newline and `Version="3.02.108"`

Or,

- `n;` - prints the current pattern space, empties the current pattern space, and reads in the next line of input (so, the difference with above is that the first "context" line is dropped from the string the substitution command will work on, and there will be no need matching `\n` that [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276782/sed-wont-match-next-line/58277024#comment102923343_58277024) across all `sed` versions)
- `s/Version.*/Version="3.02.108"/`  - replaces the substring starting with `Version` and up to the string end with a `Version="3.02.108"` text.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/NoqwBj)

Comment: Use the `n` command and there is no need to match the newline, just match the beginning of the line using the `^` meta character. Some versions of sed do not allow the `\n` in a regexp.